# Load JSON data into DataTables from POST

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, post, datatables

I have a DataTable and I load data into it using an URL this way:

```
my_data_table.ajax.url("myurl").load();
```

It works fine, but this is a GET, I need to do the same but using POST method instead, cause I have to pass content. How can I do the same but for a POST method?